# make: trying to pass git_commit_id to variable in make_file

Tags: git, shell, makefile

I am trying to get the git commit id and pass it to a script as a command line value to a file that I've compiled in cpp. To this end I've written the following snipped it my makefile.

```
%.cool_stuff:  %.c cool_stuff.cpp 
    $(CXX) $(OPT) cool_stuff.cpp -include $< -o $@ -l sqlite3 
    git_commit_id=$(shell $$(git rev-parse HEAD))
    ./$@ 1 $(git_commit_id)
```

The problem is that when I run the code, part of the output contains the statement:

> /bin/sh: 1: cdc8bdff6ccbc9dd14da68343fe4809f02cbe07e: not found

so that nothing ends up getting passed for $(git_commit_id) to the last line of the snippet.

please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Waayyyyy too many layers of interpreter invocation. Try

```
%.cool_stuff:  %.c cool_stuff.cpp 
    $(CXX) $(OPT) cool_stuff.cpp -include $< -o $@ -l sqlite3
    git_commit_id=`git rev-parse HEAD`; \
    ./$@ 1 $$git_commit_id
```

(edit: corrections from comments; also: note that markdown formatting eats tabs, don't c&p without replacing leading spaces with leading tabs).

Comment: Although for traditional make, where each line is passed to a separate shell, you'll need to set the variable and then use it immediately. (gmake has a non-traditional mode that will work with this form.)

Comment: This will only work with the `ONE_SHELL` directive; typically, make invokes each like in a separate shell, so I’d prefer `./$@ 1 "$$(git rev-parse HEAD)"`

Comment: gakk.  "I knew that."   Fixed. @torek

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I actually had that in there and took it out to preserve the variable assignment, wasn't thinking, fixed.

Comment: To be completely clear, the backslash at the end of the first line is not needed and, in fact, is probably not a good idea.  By adding that in you're losing any error result you might get from the compilation line which you definitely don't want to do.  Either you should remove the backslash at the end of the first line (you don't need it) or replace the `;` here with `&&` to short-circuit the commands on failure.

Comment: Also, the entire thing is simpler to read (IMO) if you forgo the variable entirely and just write: `./$@ 1 \`git rev-parse HEAD\`` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the `$(shell..)` command in a call to eval as shown below

```
$(eval git_commit_id=$(shell git rev-parse HEAD))
```